# How do I make a blazor button that passes an int

Tags: c#, button, blazor-client-side

I have been working on "https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5264915/Explore-Blazor-WebAssembly-use-custom-style-calle#ptwwwcicpagafwai" and have mostly got it working.

In this project is a page, Working.razor, which uses 4 buttons to call a method, each with a different parameter, an example follows:
`<button class="w3-button w3-large w3-amber" @onClick="() => Generate(5)">Five</button>`
No errors and no response.

I have hard coded the Generate(5) method, which makes the page do what it is built for, that is to generate dummy data for insertion into an IBM Cloudant database. So after a few modifications the whole thing works, except for those 4 buttons.

I have tried: `<button class="w3-button w3-large w3-amber" @onClick="Generate(1)">One</button>` which also does nothing, and a few variations on: `@onClick="@(() => Generate(5))"`. That last one gives the error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type". Generate(int) is a void method.

I would like to understand how these buttons were supposed to work and how to make a button that will successfully pass an integer to the Generate method.

Comment: I think it's just a small typo: use `@onclick=` instead of `@onClick=`

Comment: I found it before seeing this comment. You were right. I wasted a lot of time looking past this.

Answer (score 0):

`<button class="w3-button w3-large w3-amber" @onclick = "@(() => Generate(1))">One</button>`

It is embarrassing to admit that what finally made this work was the lower case c in onclick. Not being familiar with this syntax, I looked many ways at only one of the issues and never saw the simple one until today.